# Query to subtract all numbers in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update, subtraction

I don't think code should be necessary here but let me know if you'd like it anyways.

I had to delete an entire set of entries in one of my tables. These entries were being organized by a integer value that increased with intervals. Is there a way that I can write a query so that all the values in a particular column will update with a -1 value?

So for example, lets say I had this table

```
| Red    | 1 |
| Orange | 2 |
| Yellow | 3 |
| Green  | 4 |
| Cyan   | 6 |
| Blue   | 7 |
| Purple | 8 |
| Violet | 9 |
```

could I write a single query so that cyan - violet's numbers all subtracted by one rather than doing a unique update for every entry?

```
| Red    | 1 |
| Orange | 2 |
| Yellow | 3 |
| Green  | 4 |
| Cyan   | 5 |
| Blue   | 6 |
| Purple | 7 |
| Violet | 8 |
```

Comment: `update yourtable set field=field-1 where color in ('cyan', 'blue', ....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Cte` to update and `Row_number()` to generate sequential numbers

```
; WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ( Row_number()OVER( ORDER BY id) )rn,*
         FROM   yourtable)
UPDATE cte
SET    id = rn
```